# PHP sqlsrv_get_field returns always blank

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm wondering why `sqlsrv_get_field($stmt,0)` is not working: it always returns blank while for example sqlsrv_fetch_array finds results. For example:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
};
```

this is returning data for the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving row fields by name is not supported by `sqlsrv_get_field`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-get-field.php

```
sqlsrv_fetch($stmt);
$title = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0);
echo $title;
```

Comment: I don't get your answer...where do I try to retrieve a field by name with `sqlsrv_get_field` in the code I've posted? I'm using exactly the code you've posted in my original code...

Comment: You should add `sqlsrv_fetch` before `sqlsrv_get_field`

Comment: @Mark `sqlsrv_get_field` access fields by index. If you use `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC`, you will fetch row columns by names. Try using `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC` or `SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH`.